# Adding an exception to a resource calendar for a working day on a defined non-working day throws out % Complete value

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have written a macro that reads timesheet data and updates the TimeScaleData in the project to update the status.

A staff member works on the occasional Saturday or a Sunday, which are defined as a non-working days in the base calendar. The macro adds an exception to the resource's calendar for a working day but it throws out the % Complete calculations.

The code for creating the exception:

```vb
If Not r.Calendar.Period(timesheetDate).Working Then
    Dim e As Exception
    Set e = r.Calendar.Exceptions.Add(Type:=pjDaily, Start:=timsheetDate, Finish:=timesheetDate, Occurrences:=1, Name:="Non Standard Work Day")
    e.Shift1.Start = proj.DefaultStartTime
    e.Shift1.Finish = #1:00:00 PM#
    e.shift2.Start = #1:24:00 PM#
    e.Shift2.Finish = proj.DefaultFinishTime
End If
```

The code for updating the % Complete for the selected task to the Status Date:

```
Application.UpdateProject All:=False, UpdateDate:=proj.StatusDate, Action:=pj0to100Percent
```

You can see the effect.
[image: screenshot]

The Status Date is the 17th but the % Complete bar in the centre of the task bar is showing approximately 1.5 working days after the status date.

As expected, this doesn't occur when I add the exception to the base calendar but it then changes that weekend to a working day for all resources.

Comment: This is a very well-posed question, however it may be better suited for the [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/) site. Do you see the same behavior if you do these steps through the user-interface? If so, see if you can find a solution working through the UI and once you have that, translate it to code. It appears that Project simply doesn't show the % Complete correctly in this situation and if that is important, you'll need to find a work-around. However, the experts at the PM site might know a way around this.

Comment: Thanks Rachel, yes, the same behaviour occurs when I complete the same steps through the UI. I'll have a play around with it and see if I can find any clues towards a solution, though I suspect this is just how project behaves. If nothing presents itself I'll try a post under the PM site. Appreciate the direction.